# Dreamhost VPS Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess

This is a very unusual problem to begin with. Most people are having trouble with the `.htaccess` where they accidentally are denying permissions and want to fix that. I have the opposite problem. I want to deny permissions several directories but my `.htaccess` isn't working. The current directive in the file is

```
<Directory ./*> 
     order deny,allow
     deny from all
</Directory>
```

In practice it should give me an internal service error with a status code of 500. I tested this on windows and [it works as expected.] The directive however doesn't work on my ubuntu apache 2.2 vps server. I already checked to make sure that `AllowOverride all` was on in my other directive files. I also reset apache and httpd to see if that was the problem and the end result was no. For some reason I can't get the server to read this `.htaccess`.

Any help with be appreciated, I already spent more hours than I would like to admit on this problem and I can't find an answer anywhere on the web or server fault.

Comment: You should contact Dreamhost. [It is unlikely that you will be able to fix this yourself.](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3t8727/dreamhost_is_removing_sudo_access_from_existing/)

Answer (score 0):

For Making Apache's .htaccess to work, following configuration must be present.

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Directory /DOC_ROOT>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Do you have this configuration?.